# c# - adding label value to query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms

I want to add the label value which is a number add it to query I try the query below but It returns a Data mismatch.

```
OleDbDataAdapter db = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Count <= '" + label3.Text + "'", con);
```

Comment: Can you add in the exact error you are receiving? Also, I would suggest creating a parameterized query instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: 1. Drop apostrophes 2. Count is a reserved word, put it in brackets

Comment: the error is `Data type mismatch in criteria expression`

Comment: Could you provide information about where to find your app? :D Just kidding... Anyway you should look into parameterized queries - see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**update** I am surprised, this works for you, since there are some issueses here. The statement, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Count(*) <= 3
```

is a bit strange, since there is no grouping of any kind.

To count the rows in a table you can use this statement:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM mytable
```

In your case as I understood, the statement;

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM mytable HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3;
```

will only return rows if there are less or equal than 3 rows in the table.

---

**original**

Skip the `'`. In this case you are referring to an actual number and not a string.

```
new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Count(*) <= " + label3.Text, con);
```

And as @DmitryBychenko stated, you need to count "something".

Comment: Not enough. Look at the comment above

Comment: Ah, yes, the count bracket remark.

Comment: it works. thanks mate

Comment: Also, just a suggestion, if the OP insists on continuing with string concatenation, it would probably be better to use something like `new OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE [Count] <= {0};", int.Parse(label3.Text).ToString()), con)`, but better would be to insist on using parameterized queries.

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(1) ...`, not `where` - let be Ansi compartible

Comment: Actually, my answer don't make sense at all....

Comment: It is the question that should provide the sence (what is the goal of the query). I can't see any better answer as a query without syntax errors

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Agree, if the `Count` is indeed meant to be `Count(1)` instead, then definitely use `HAVING` for aggregates. I am not sure if the OP is using it that way or if it is meant as a field from their table, in which case `[Count]` or `"Count"` (depending on the DBMS) within the `WHERE` clause would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming InventoryCount is an integer, you are comparing an int to a string.

The correct query would be:

```
OleDbDataAdapter db = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM DropsSyrupSusppension WHERE InventoryCount <= " + label3.Text, con);
```